# Attempting to get two INSERT's to two different database tables with one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I am attempting to send the exact same information to two different tables. I read that this cannot be done with one INSERT query, so I tried doing this.

```
 $stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_players (user_id, firstname, lastname, username, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO drafted_players (user_id, firstname, lastname, username, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    if ( false===$stmt2 ) {
         // Check Errors for prepare
        die('Add to user players prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    $stmt2->bind_param('issss', $shuffle_id, $shuffle_firstname, $shuffle_lastname, $shuffle_username, $shuffle_email);

    foreach ($_POST['id'] as $i => $shuffle_id) {
        $shuffle_firstname = $_POST['firstname'][$i];
        $shuffle_lastname = $_POST['lastname'][$i];
        $shuffle_username = $_POST['username'][$i];
        $shuffle_email = $_POST['email'][$i];
        $stmt2->execute() or
            die('Add to user players execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
```

And only the second insert part is working. How can I structure this, so that both INSERT's work?

Comment: But why? Never store the same data twice.

Comment: It won't be the same data twice. Just initially upon insert. But the first query, I need to save that info the way it is inserted. The second query gets modified.

Comment: Can't you have one table for all players? And either a column indicating drafted or else?

Comment: The players will change all of the time. Though the players drafted need to be documented and saved, as they will need to be used later on. The active players change week to week, so the players drafted would be lost if this was only in one table.

Comment: I'd still go with one table, with a column status that can have the values active, drafted and inactive.

Comment: @jarlh To be honest, I am not at a level yet where I could execute this. IT may be the best route, but until I am at that point, I have to do things this way. Thank you though, I really do appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `$stmt2` twice - if you have two prepared statements, you need two variables to store them. If you change your code to:

```
$stmt1 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_players (user_id, firstname, lastname, username, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO drafted_players (user_id, firstname, lastname, username, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

if ( false===$stmt1 || false===$stmt2 ) {
     // Check Errors for prepare
    die('Add to user players prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
}
$stmt1->bind_param('issss', $shuffle_id, $shuffle_firstname, $shuffle_lastname, $shuffle_username, $shuffle_email);
$stmt2->bind_param('issss', $shuffle_id, $shuffle_firstname, $shuffle_lastname, $shuffle_username, $shuffle_email);

foreach ($_POST['id'] as $i => $shuffle_id) {
    $shuffle_firstname = $_POST['firstname'][$i];
    $shuffle_lastname = $_POST['lastname'][$i];
    $shuffle_username = $_POST['username'][$i];
    $shuffle_email = $_POST['email'][$i];
    $stmt1->execute() or
        die('Add to user players execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt1->error));
    $stmt2->execute() or
        die('Add to user players execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
```

it should work.

Comment: This mostly worked. for reason reason the lastname isn't sending for either?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Do you mean the column lastname is  still empty? If so, please double-check the form (or whatever is sending the data to this PHP page) - perhaps it is spelled differently, like `lastName` there.

Comment: Everything is spelled right. The lastname sent before I added the extra query?

Answer (score 0):

You can also send both commands in one statement (preferably with named parameters)

```
$statement = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_players    (user_id, firstname, lastname, username, email) VALUES (:user_id, :firstname, :lastname, :username, :email);  
                            INSERT INTO drafted_players (user_id, firstname, lastname, username, email) VALUES (:user_id, :firstname, :lastname, :username, :email);");

$statement->bindValue('user_id', $shuffle_id);
...
```